# vba for.... to loop query. Filling in cells in Excel

Tags: vba

Hi could you please advise why the below code is not working? I would like to fill in the cells with "aaaa". 
I am VBA beginner and would appreciate if you provide some theorethical reference. Thank you

```
Sub aa()
   Dim row As Integer
   Dim col As Integer

   For row = 1 To 20
       For col = 1 To 20
           Cells(row, col) = "aaaa"

       Next row
   Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Next row` and `Next col` are mixed. And btw how exactly `code is not working?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it is important for you to learn the Pragmatics of VBA.

Always remember that when you are working with a nested for loop, make sure that you are calling the right "next" instance for that loop.

In your code, the "next row" should be on the outer for loop, and the "next col" should be in the inner loop.

```
Sub aa()
   Dim row As Integer
   Dim col As Integer

   For row = 1 To 20
       For col = 1 To 20
           Cells(row, col) = "aaaa"

       Next col
   Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Further, you do not need to actually specify the variable in `next` statements, and omitting them is often a good step when you encounter a `for` loop error

Comment: @TaylorScott While you do not need them, writing them may be best for readability and maintenance.